# How can I catch and modify SOAP request

Tags: php, soap

I need to write a small demo to send and serve a SOAP function, and then modify the request to show the vulnerable.

I can catch the SOAP message in XML form in wireshark, but it seems that I can't modify it. I tried some proxy program but no luck.

I'm using Ubuntu 10.10 amd64 and my client is written in PHP

Comment: SOAP UI lets you change the values of the SOAP request  and see the response immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check out SOAPUI (http://www.soapui.org/)  There is an open source version of it.  Also take a look at Fiddler.    It can act as a proxy and is pretty easy to use.  I have used it extensively to look at web requests & responses but not for SOAP work myself

Comment: soapui seems fit my need, i'm using Ubuntu Linux so I think I can't use Fiddler, forgot to include it in my question